# Paraview - get current time_index in ProgrammableSource

Tags: paraview

I have an array that has exactly as many rows as there are time steps in the animation. Now I want to have the row associated to the current time step as vtkTable as output of a ProgrammableSource. My code (for the ProgrammableSource) so far looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

file = "table.csv"
tbl = np.genfromtxt(file, names=True, delimiter=",", autostrip=True)
for n in tbl.dtype.names:
    v = tbl[n][2]
    output.RowData.append(v, n)
```

Which currently always writes out the third line (v = tbl[n][2]). Is there a way to pass the current time step (index) in place of [2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to make your `Programmable Source` timesteps aware.

So you should fill the `Information Script` (advanced property) to declare the list of available timesteps, and then in the main script, get current timestep and output the data you want.

See this [example](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/pythonProgrammableFilter.html#reading-a-csv-file-series) from the doc.